# Can I create a parameter in a Local?

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I created a Derived Column with a Expression

(dummy sample)
`iif(columnX=='true',1,0)`

This expression will be util in anothers Derived Columns, so I'd like create a Local with this Expression, but in the place of columnX I'll put a parameter for another column

Is it possible? How?

Comment: Hi, Can you please give more details on your scenario?  "This expression will be util in anothers Derived Columns" - it is used in a derived column within same data flow?

Comment: Hi, in my scenario I'll import data from a .csv file. The file have columns the user can input text like boolean (yes/no), but the user can write in many ways (yes, Yes, YES, y, true...)
My expression handle the input
iif(columnX=='true',1,iif(columnX=='yes', 1, iif(columnX=='y',1, 0)))

Answer (score 0):

I tried creating a data flow parameter (param2) and added your expression to it using a different parameter (param1) instead of ColumnX.

[image]

But I was not able to change the parameter value in the expression later, it was only taking the default value. Also did not find any related documents to assign a column value to a parameter in the data flow.

The only way I could think of is, using the expression multiple times in different derived columns taking different columns in place of ColumnX.

- Derived column1: Added expression to the new column (col1)

[image]

- Preview of Derived column1: Evaluating expression against Sample1 column.

[image]

- Derived column2: Reusing same column name Col1 to evaluate the expression against Sample2 column. If the previous value is needed, you can assign the previous value of Col1 to the new column (previous_col1) in derived column2 as shown in the below snip.

[image]

- Preview of derived column2

[image]